# How to fix, Input string not in correct format unity 3d and serial

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serial-port

I am using unity 3d to visualise a serial output from an Arduino and keep geting the error

> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>   System.Number.StringToNumber (System.String str,
>   System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Number+NumberBuffer&
>   number, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info, System.Boolean
>   parseDecimal) (at <599589bf4ce248909b8a14cbe4a2034e>:0)
>   System.Number.ParseInt32 (System.String s,
>   System.Globalization.NumberStyles style,
>   System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) (at
>   <599589bf4ce248909b8a14cbe4a2034e>:0) System.Int32.Parse
>   (System.String s, System.IFormatProvider provider) (at
>   <599589bf4ce248909b8a14cbe4a2034e>:0) System.Convert.ToInt32
>   (System.String value) (at <599589bf4ce248909b8a14cbe4a2034e>:0)
>   One_mputest.Update () (at Assets/One_mputest.cs:48)

i have tried using plugins and they did not work

C# script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class One_mputest : MonoBehaviour {

private int x;
private int y;
private int z;

private int roll;
private int pitch;
private int yaw;

static SerialPort serial = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    serial.ReadTimeout = 5000;
    if (!serial.IsOpen) {
        try {
            serial.Open ();
        } catch (TimeoutException) {

        }

    } else
        Debug.LogError ("Port already open");
    }

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (!serial.IsOpen)
        serial.Open ();

    string ypr = serial.ReadLine ();

    List<String> stringList = ypr.Split('\t').ToList();

    int[] intArray = new int[7];

    for (int s = 0; s < 7; s++)
    {
        intArray[s] = Convert.ToInt32(stringList[s]);
    }

    x = intArray[3];
    y = intArray[0];
    z = intArray[1];

    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(z, y, x);
}
```

}

The serial input:

```
-104.65  -10     5   65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.74  -4  1   65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.19  -2  0   65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.09  0   0   65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-101.75  0   0   65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-101.61  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-101.62  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-101.68  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-101.76  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.02  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.20  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.33  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.43  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.57  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.77  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.90  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.68  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.48  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.26  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.01  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-101.83  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.15  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.34  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.17  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-101.89  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-101.74  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-101.88  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-101.95  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.01  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.05  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.06  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.00  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-101.96  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.06  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.14  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.37  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    
-102.81  0   -1  65536.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

I expected the vector variable to change and move the object that the script was applied to

and only got the error about:  Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: Parsing strings to proper values is notoriously tricky. As a general rule, you should be using TryParse(). However as you have not told us wich value you want each serial input to the parsed into, we can not help you. I mean what number(s) **should** "-104.65 -10 5 65536.00 0.00 0.00 0.00" be parsed to?

Comment: What is the value of `stringList[s]` and `stringList[s].Length` when the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try & catch are your friends. It's possible there is an extra `\t` in the file and you are trying to convert a `null` into a number somewhere. Also a good tip is always use {} around if statements just to make sure nothing unexpected happens *(eg: you think something is inside an if statement but it's outside)*

One point I would look at is that you are trying to convert a `String` representing a `Float` to an `Int32`, this may be where things are going wrong.

Try something like this:

```
void Update () {
    var whatdoing = "starting try";

    try {
        if (!serial.IsOpen) {
            serial.Open (); }

        whatdoing               = "reading line";
        string ypr              = serial.ReadLine ();

        List<String> stringList = ypr.Split('\t').ToList();
        int[] intArray          = new int[7];

         for (int s = 0; s < 7; s++) {
             whatdoing = "converting: " + stringList[s];

             if(!Int.TryParse(stringList[s], out intArray[s]) {
                 throw new Exception("Could not parse string to Int: "+whatdoing); } }
          whatdoing = "Assigning xyz";
          x         = intArray[3];
          y         = intArray[0];
          z         = intArray[1];

          transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(z, y, x);}
catch(Exception e) {
 BREAK HERE and check exception & whatdoing.
} }
```